# improve search performance of mongodb for non shared keys

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I have some sample json like below.

```
 {
       "userid":1,
       "name":"test",
       "phone":"7878787878",
       "email":"test@mail.com",
       "uuid":"testingOne",
       "location":"ZoneA"
    }
```

I selected shard key as **userid**, since it has good cardinality.

```
db.userDetails.createIndex( { "userid": 1 }, { unique: true } )
db.userDetails.createIndex( { "phone": 1 } )
db.userDetails.createIndex( { "email": 1 } )
db.userDetails.createIndex( { "name": 1 } )

sh.shardCollection( "userDB.userDetails", { userid: "hashed" } )
```

Now there is a extra requirement, there are queries which may need search based on the phone or email but they are very rare.
So I dont want to again shard based on these new search keys, I just enabled indexing.

So now the Questions is

1. What is the worst case search latency for these just indexed keys.
2. If I have 5 shards, is there option to force  mongo to execute this kind of search on all the shards parallelely

Is there better way to fasten the search without shard

Comment: Remember back to when you were asking which shard key to choose and I was basically leading you to realize you probably did not yet need sharding if you did not understand which one to choose? This is pretty much the same type of question. Look at at [Hashed vs Ranged Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/) and the two different diagrams and try to realize what "hashed" actually does here. The question really is way too broad and you should understand why it's too broad as there are just "too many variables" here.

Comment: From a very basic standpoint,  you basically have two design principles. 1. You actually **want** requests to cluster to a particular shard and use ranges to do so. Here you might just have common queries and operations which are going to work on data residing on a single shard without needing to "go everywhere". 2. You actually want to distribute **everything** as evenly as possible across all shards. This is a case where "hashing" works because it's meant to evenly distribute the data, which also means an even distribution of requests.

Comment: I understand., thanks for detailed explanation, in my case distributing data I can choose a proper shard key, so I should use a same shared key while doing search.  
But as I had mentioned, I also do search based on extra keys and it will be very rare, but its repose is slow due to scatter and gather.
What about keeping mapping collections with other search key as a shard key,  like original collection with shard key as user id, then new mapping collection with phone number as a shard and it will have "{phone:"", userid:""}  .